# Date comparison still returning false

Tags: bash

A bash file in azure pipeline task is failing in the job for bash. I created a sample script file and could see that it is the same error from the bash file. The result_swap should be True, but somehow the condition is jumping to false.  This is the code below :
`

```
    #!/bin/bash
    printf -v date '%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n' -1
            echo $date
            swapdate="2022-01-19"
            swapstatus="True"
            if [ "$date" = "$swapdate" ] && [ "$swapstatus" = "True" ]; then
            echo "yes!, it is equal and condition is true continue swapping"
            result_swap="true"
            echo $swapdate
            echo $date
            echo $result_swap
            echo $swapstatus
            else
            result_swap="false"
            echo "no!, it is not equal"
            echo $swapdate
            echo $date
            echo $result_swap
            echo $swapstatus
            
            fi
```

`

Comment: Replace `$swapdate="2022-01-19"` by `swapdate="2022-01-19"`. Same for `swapstatus`. You assign bash variable `foo` with `foo=something` (like you do correctly for `result_swap`) and you expand the variable (that is, get its value) with `$foo`.

Comment: You should have seen *some* error involving a failure to find the command `=2022-01-19`. You aren't actually defining `swapdate` or `swapstatus`. Use http://shellcheck.net to find common errors in your scripts.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo, since you correctly define `result_swap` in the script.

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting this and many other common shell scripting mistakes; I recommend running your scripts through it and fixing what it points out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `date` ends with a newline; the value of `swapdate` does not. Drop the `\n` in the definition.

```
printf -v date '%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n' -1  # NO
printf -v date '%(%Y-%m-%d)T' -1  # YES
```